# Delay between SPI.write() calls

Tags: c++, spi, mbed

I'm using a RedBearLabs Blend V2 to communicate with a SPI peripheral. Everything is functioning correctly at this point and I am receiving the expected data using `SPI.write()` and catching the return value. The SPI bus is running at 1 MHz in mode 0.

The image below shows the SPI bus connected to a scope. Trace 1 is SCLK, 2 is MISO, 3 is MOSI and 4 is CS. As you can see, I have 4 bursts of SCLK whilst CS is low, each 8 bits in length with a delay of approximately 20 µs in between each burst. ***Ideally*, I need to completely alleviate this 20 µs delay and have *1 SCLK burst of 32 cycles*.**

[image: Scope grab of SPI bus]

The below code is how I am currently achieving what is seen in the scope grab.

```
int16_t MAX1300::sampleChannel(uint8_t channel, uint8_t inputMode, uint8_t adcMode) 
{    
    int16_t sample;
    int8_t hi = 0;
    int8_t lo = 0;

    MAX1300::InputWord_u word;
    word.bits.start = 0b1;

    if (inputMode == MAX1300::SINGLE_ENDED) {
        word.bits.select = (Channels_se_e)channel;    
    } else {
        word.bits.select = (Channels_dif_e)channel;   
    }   
    word.bits.payload = 0b0000;

    if (adcMode == MAX1300::EXT_CLK) {
        m_cs = 0;
        m_spiBus.write(word.all);
        m_spiBus.write(7);
        hi = m_spiBus.write(0);
        lo = m_spiBus.write(0);
        m_cs = 1; 
    }

    sample = ((int16_t)hi << 8) | lo;  
    return sample; 
}
```

So far I have tried setting `SPI.format(16, 0)` with the intention of having 2 SCLK bursts of 16 cycles, however the SPI bus no longer functions if I do this. The same happens if I use `SPI.transfer()` with 32-bit buffers - no SPI bus.

I am able to increase the frequency of the bus, thus reducing the delay between each SCLK burst, however this is not really a suitable solution due to the end-application for this device.

What am I doing wrong here, or is what I am attempting to do just not possible with this hardware/firmware combination?

Thanks, Adam

Comment: (Not specific to your HW, as I don't know it) Is there any SPI FIFO? Can it be driven with DMA? 20us delay is quite long - are library abstractions at fault maybe? 32-bit transfers would also make sense - but it appears there is missing HW or SW support.

Comment: There's not a FIFO on the board but it can be driven by DMA so that might be the way forward. It seems that the profiles of mbed OS provides a very-much generic wrapper and heavily limits SPI functionality despite the functionality being available in HW. So, I guess, if this issue does turn out to be a bottleneck, a custom SPI driver is the way forward!